# Convert std::tuple to std::variant recursively

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming

Need an idea on what technique to use to declare `std::variant` type containing all the types included into a given `std::tuple` and its sub-tuples (if an element is also a tuple) recursively.

For example,

```
std::tuple<int, std::tuple<int, double, std::tuple<float, double, std::string>>>
```

transforms into

```
std::variant<int, double, float, std::string>
```

in short, I need to include all the unique types into `std::variant`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html), this isn't so bad.

The first step is to recursively flatten the input list. We have `mp_flatten`, but that only does a single flattening - we need to invoke it recursively. There may be a better way to do this, but the best I've come up with so far is to use `mp_iterate` with a function that flattens only if that does something:

```
// maybe_flatten succeeds only if it actually flattens
// (once we're flat, it's ill-formed, we use that a terminating condition for mp_iterate)
template <typename L,
    typename U=mp_flatten<L>,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<not mp_same<L, U>::value>>
using maybe_flatten = U;

template <typename L>
using recursive_flatten = mp_back<mp_iterate<L, mp_identity_t, maybe_flatten>>;
```

Once we have a `recursive_flatten`, then all we need to do is ensure the types are unique and rename it to variant:

```
template <typename L>
using to_variant = mp_rename<mp_unique<recursive_flatten<L>>, std::variant>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/FyRsiZ).

---

I've been experimenting with a threading metafunction here (a la Clojure's `->`) so that you can write the functions invoked in order. I'm not sure it's better:

```
template <typename L>
using recursive_flatten2 = thread<
    mp_iterate<L, mp_identity_t, maybe_flatten>,
    mp_back>;    

template <typename L>
using to_variant2 = thread_q<
    L,
    mp_quote<recursive_flatten2>,
    mp_quote<mp_unique>,
    mp_bind_q<mp_quote<mp_apply_q>, mp_quote<std::variant>, _1>
    >;
```

[Demo w/ thread](https://godbolt.org/z/7x9xYv).